# Finding whether the lines in the image are straight (linear) or curved

Tags: python, image-processing

I have the following image, this image takes values between 0 and 9. Our matrix size is a 512*512 matrix.
Here, my aim is to look at this matrix and I want to find out whether the lines in the image are straight (linear) or curved. I added an image as an example, but I don't know how to do it. i need help on this.

[image]

This is my matrix : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14h0OD316tMNP-JKhTP4xpFI9Y293-5QN/view?usp=sharing

To read this array you have to use :

```
with open('test.npy', 'rb') as f:
    a = np.load(f)
print(a)
```

Comment: You have a 512x512 pixel PNG file with 10 unique colours. You want to look at the lines in the picture and say if they are straight... but you haven't said which lines you mean, how long/straight they need to be, nor whether the example you give is straight in your eyes, nor given a second example that is curved - or straight depending how you perceive this one. Please try to clarify your question. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell https://www.hizliresim.com/jme03pn
As an example, I can say: I want to check whether the yellow lines you see in the image are straight or not.